# Определить количество повторений слова в текстах и номера этих текстов

Tags: python

Имеется новый словарь вида:

```
texts2 = [{'id': 1, 'text': 'Шла Саша по шоссе'}, {'id': 2, 'text': 'Ехал Грека через реку'}, {'id': 3, 'text': 'Где труд там и счастье'}, {'id': 4, 'text': 'Доброта и труд рядом живут'}]
```

Необходимо определить количество повторений каждого слова и в каких текстах оно встречается, чтобы получить список:

```
result = {"word": "труд", "count": 2, "id": [3, 4]}
```

Есть функция, которая может реализовать данный алгоритм. На вход она принимает словарь и какое-либо слово.

```
def number_of_occurrences(text, word):
        res = {"word": word, "count": 0, "id": []}
        for key, value in text.items():
            n = value.count(word)
            if n:
                res["count"] += n
                res["id"].append(key)
        return res

number_of_occurrences(texts, 'труд')
```

Но в данном случае в качестве словаря используются старые данные:

```
texts = {1 : 'Шла Саша по шоссе', 2 :'Ехал Грека через реку', 3 : 'Где труд там и счастье', 4 : 'Доброта и труд рядом живут'}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать эту функцию,чтобы она работала правильно со словарем texts2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

сначала собрал бы словарь, затем перевел бы в список

кроме того использовал бы `set` при сборе `id` вместо списка, чтобы не добавлять повторяющиеся `id` (например для случая текста `вышли вышли мы на улицу вышли`)

```
texts = [{'id': 1, 'text': 'Шла Саша по шоссе'}, {'id': 2, 'text': 'Ехал Грека через реку'}, {'id': 3, 'text': 'Где труд там и счастье'}, {'id': 4, 'text': 'Доброта и труд рядом живут'}]

tmp = dict()

for text in texts:
    for word in text['text'].split():
        tmp[word] = tmp.get(word, {'count': 0, 'id': set()})

        tmp[word]['count'] += 1
        tmp[word]['id'].add(text['id'])

res = [{'word': word, 'count': tmp[word]['count'], 'id': list([tmp[word]['id']])} for word in tmp]

print(res)
```

Конкретно для вашей задачи (с учетом того, что вы дополнили условие) ваша функция должна выглядеть так:

```
texts = [{'id': 1, 'text': 'Шла Саша по шоссе'}, {'id': 2, 'text': 'Ехал Грека через реку'}, {'id': 3, 'text': 'Где труд там и счастье'}, {'id': 4, 'text': 'Доброта и труд рядом живут'}]

def number_of_occurrences(word, texts):
    res = {"word": word, "count": 0, "id": []}
    for text in texts:
        n = text['text'].lower().count(word)
        if n:
            res["count"] += n
            if text['id'] not in res["id"]:
                res["id"].append(text['id'])

    return res

print(number_of_occurrences('шла', texts))
```

я специально перевел текст в нижний регистр, чтобы `шла` и `Шла` воспринимались как одно слово

Comment: Да, сам хотел такой ответ  отправить)

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, а если имеется список слов, для которых необходимо найти количество повторений и номера текстов, как тогда решить задачу? например: words = [ 'шла', 'шоссе' ,'труд', 'доброта', 'реку']

Comment: Елена, не совсем понял вопрос

Comment: я немного исправила условие задачи. моя функция как раз принимает на вход какое то слово и словарь texts. а мне необходимо чтобы на вход подавалось слово и список словарей texts2, для которого эта функция не работает как надо

Comment: по хорошему мне нужно изменить мою эту функцию для тех входных данных что я указала

Comment: т.е. вам нужно переделать для вашего входа?

Comment: добавил в свой ответ пример переделки вашего кода - там надо было параметры местами поменять и перевести текст в нижний регистр

Comment: извините, но Вы в качестве входных данных взяли не то. мне нужно чтоб на вход подавался список словарей texts2, как прописано в условии. а Вы взяли старые данные texts

Comment: я теперь совсем запутался - новый словарь - это какой? старый словарь - это какой? вы бы привели тогда свой вопрос к какому-то окончательному виду и убрали бы ненужный/старый код

Comment: я исправила условие, можете пожалуйста посмотреть

Comment: это оказалось так просто...спасибо вам большое

Comment: теперь понял - внес правку в свой ответ (последний код), и добавил код, чтобы не было дублирования слов, если слова встречаются в 1 тексте несколько раз, я предпочитаю использовать множества, но тут пришлось через поиск делать